# How to Pass data that changes based on time from Activity to Service

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, background

What's the best way to pass data that is changing based on time from the Activity to Service?

Or the best way to initially pass it and handle it from a Background Service?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple Bundles or for after usage u can store data locally using SharedPreferences

more info:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html